# Ajax search suggestions don't work

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, search

I want to search by SKU but suggestions don't appear.

For example, most SKU start by "600", the ajax request made by Magento 2.x is:

> search/ajax/suggest/?q=600&_=1571930826272

The result is

> {}

SKU field is searchable and active, why does it return 0 results?

Comment: This may be obvious, did you change the Minimal query length? config->catalog->catalog

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in magento 2.3.1

Take a look at https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9988